# Bash script to read variable from text file

Tags: bash

I would like to have the following in a text file

```
name=missy email=missy@example.com
```

Is it possible to read that into a text file and be able to call the variables $name and $email

Or what is the best way of doing this?

Thank you for all the help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Are you trying to _read from_ a text file, or to _write into_ it ?

Comment: Read from it and use in a bash script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is the first way that comes to mind:

```
#!bash
# set for loop separator to newline
IFS=$'\n'
# loop through each line in the file
for userline in $(cat email_list.txt); do
    # Cut delimiter is a space for the next two lines
    # echo the line into cut, grab the first field as the user
    user=$(echo "$userline" | cut -d' ' -f1)
    # echo the line into cut, grab the second field as the email
    email=$(echo "$userline" | cut -d' ' -f2)

    # Set the delimiter an =, grab field 2
    user=$(echo "$user" | cut -d'=' -f2)
    # Set the delimiter an =, grab field 2
    email=$(echo "$email" | cut -d'=' -f2)

    echo "Username: ${user}, email address: ${email}"
done
```

email_list.txt:

```
name=missy email=missy@example.com
name=joe email=joe@smoe.com
```

Output:

```
Username: missy, email address: missy@example.com
Username: joe, email address: joe@smoe.com
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  However, it depends on what you are doing with it, and how many records you have in your file.